# Ruby Code Explanation: Numbers to String using Recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

Someone shared some Ruby code on how they completed a challenge where you have to convert numbers into words. This solution was by far the simplest to read, but I do not completely understand the recursive aspect of it. Specifically, in the line below...

```
elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
  return str + "#{name}"
```

If a return statement breaks code out of a loop, why wouldn't this code execute and break the loop once it is true? For example, when int = 4 and num = 1, this would prove to be true and trigger the return statement, yet the code continues until num = 4.

Any clarification on that aspect of the code, as well as any general advice for understanding this solution, would be helpful. Still trying to understand recursion. Thanks

```
def in_words(int)
  numbers_to_name = {
      1000000 => "million",
      1000 => "thousand",
      100 => "hundred",
      90 => "ninety",
      80 => "eighty",
      70 => "seventy",
      60 => "sixty",
      50 => "fifty",
      40 => "forty",
      30 => "thirty",
      20 => "twenty",
      19=>"nineteen",
      18=>"eighteen",
      17=>"seventeen", 
      16=>"sixteen",
      15=>"fifteen",
      14=>"fourteen",
      13=>"thirteen",              
      12=>"twelve",
      11 => "eleven",
      10 => "ten",
      9 => "nine",
      8 => "eight",
      7 => "seven",
      6 => "six",
      5 => "five",
      4 => "four",
      3 => "three",
      2 => "two",
      1 => "one"
    }

  str = ""
  numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
    if int == 0
      return str
    elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}"      
    elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    elsif int/num > 0
      return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    end
  end
end

puts in_words(4) == "four"
puts in_words(27) == "twenty seven"
puts in_words(102) == "one hundred two"
puts in_words(38_079) == "thirty eight thousand seventy nine"
puts in_words(82102713) == "eighty two million one hundred two thousand seven hundred thirteen"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Debugging Code

Here's a modified version with debug lines in every branch :

```
def in_words(int, indent="")
  puts "#{indent}in_words(#{int})"
  numbers_to_name = {
      1000000 => "million",
      1000 => "thousand",
      100 => "hundred",
      90 => "ninety",
      80 => "eighty",
      70 => "seventy",
      60 => "sixty",
      50 => "fifty",
      40 => "forty",
      30 => "thirty",
      20 => "twenty",
      19=>"nineteen",
      18=>"eighteen",
      17=>"seventeen", 
      16=>"sixteen",
      15=>"fifteen",
      14=>"fourteen",
      13=>"thirteen",              
      12=>"twelve",
      11 => "eleven",
      10 => "ten",
      9 => "nine",
      8 => "eight",
      7 => "seven",
      6 => "six",
      5 => "five",
      4 => "four",
      3 => "three",
      2 => "two",
      1 => "one"
    }

  str = ""
  numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
    puts "#{indent}  testing #{num}"
    if int == 0
      puts "#{indent}   Empty string"
      return str
    elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
      puts "#{indent}  Single digit found (#{name})!"
      return str + "#{name}"      
    elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      puts "#{indent}  Double digits found (#{name})!"
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
      puts "#{indent}  Recursive call with #{int%num} :"
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num, indent+"  ")
    elsif int/num > 0
      puts "#{indent}  Recursive call with #{int/num} and #{int%num} :"
      indent += "  "
      return str + in_words(int/num, indent) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num,indent)
    end
  end
end
```

For `in_words(4)`, it outputs :

```
in_words(4)
  testing 1000000
  testing 1000
  testing 100
  testing 90
  testing 80
  testing 70
  testing 60
  testing 50
  testing 40
  testing 30
  testing 20
  testing 19
  testing 18
  testing 17
  testing 16
  testing 15
  testing 14
  testing 13
  testing 12
  testing 11
  testing 10
  testing 9
  testing 8
  testing 7
  testing 6
  testing 5
  testing 4
  Single digit found (four)!
four
```

And for 27 :

```
in_words(27)
  testing 1000000
  testing 1000
  testing 100
  testing 90
  testing 80
  testing 70
  testing 60
  testing 50
  testing 40
  testing 30
  testing 20
  Double digits found (twenty)!
  Recursive call with 7 :
  in_words(7)
    testing 1000000
    testing 1000
    testing 100
    testing 90
    testing 80
    testing 70
    testing 60
    testing 50
    testing 40
    testing 30
    testing 20
    testing 19
    testing 18
    testing 17
    testing 16
    testing 15
    testing 14
    testing 13
    testing 12
    testing 11
    testing 10
    testing 9
    testing 8
    testing 7
    Single digit found (seven)!
twenty seven
```

## Answer

> For example, when int = 4 and num = 1, this would prove to be true and
>   trigger the return statement, yet the code continues until num = 4.

With `4` as input, `num = 1` will never happen. `numbers_to_name` is in decreasing order, so the return statement will happen for `num=4`, and the method won't execute any other code after that.

Comment: Ahh -- thank you! I'm now realizing that the each loop is starting from the top -- millions -- downward. Bad overlook on my part. Thank you for taking the time to show me that!!